# To get all the dates in a format dd/mm/yyyy. I have a date field in the format yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my DB, there is a date field in the format yyyymmdd.
I have to get all the dates in the format dd-mm-yyyy for that particlar date.

ex:

```
Date
20170130
20170228
20170325
```

for the above dates, I need the output in the below format with the dates and day of the particular dates

```
date                  day

30-01-2017            tuesday
28-02-2017            tuesday
25-03-2017            saturday
```

Comment: When asking questions about dates & time, one needs to be very precise about some terms, such as "date". In Oracle the "date" data type is NOT stored in any "format" (in fact they are stored as sets of integers). So, is your column a CHAR or VARCHAR2 column that looks like a date? or is it really an Oracle date data type? This matters.

Answer (score 1):

If the column is a string, then it can hold invalid date values such as `February 31`, one way to avoid this is by a small function such as this:

```
create or replace 
function my_to_date( p_str in varchar2 ) return date 
is 
begin 
return to_date( p_str ); 
exception 
when others then 
return null; 
end; 
\\


select to_char(my_to_date('20170231'),'DD-MM-YYYY Day')
from dual
\\
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OHZMKE80072)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

Select to_char(yrdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_char(yrdate, 'D') from yrtable

Comment: `to_char(yrdate, 'D')`? What is the return value from **that** function? What relationship does it have to the OP's question?

Comment: why don't you try this in your console:     select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_char(sysdate, 'D'), to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') from dual

Comment: In my console it returns the number 3. What does it return in yours? If it returns the same, how is that related to the OP's question? Don't add `'DAY'` to the test, since that is not what you wrote in the Answer.

Comment: that is the day of week. try again by changing the 'D' to 'DAY' and see the result

Comment: Are we speaking the same language? Why do I need to try? I didn't post a wrong answer, you did.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your dates aren't actually `DATE` fields but some kind of `CHAR` field? The best option would be to convert to `DATE` and then convert back to `CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(mydate, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-MM-YYYY Day')
  FROM mytable;
```

This uses the `YYYYMMDD` mask to convert your string into a date, then uses the mask `DD-MM-YYYY Day` to convert it back into a string. Use `day` if you want the day name in lowercase (as in your OP).

Comment: except if there are invalid date strings

Comment: Sure, then you could filter on valid date strings with a regex or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

@user2778168 answer will give you the results you want. But why?

Your database does not have dates stored in *yyyymmdd format* or any other date *format* for at mater, unless it's defined with a character type definition. Oracle stores all dates in a single internal structure, and with only slight variations timestamps are the same. The format used only tells Oracle how to **display** the value or to convert a string to a date. Unless a specific format is specified Oracle uses the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for this determination. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) and scan down to "Datetime Format Models" for format specifications.

To see this run the following:

```
select value
  from nls_session_parameters
 where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

Select yrdate                        default_format
     , to_char(yrdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') specified_format
     , dump(yrdate)                  unformated 
  from yrtable; 

alter session set nls_date_format = 'Month dd,yyyy';

Rerun the above queries.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you hold date column(`date1`) in character format. Suppose you have a table named `days`:

```
SQL> desc days
     date1 varchar2(10)
```

then,

we should convert it into date, and then into char format, with  aliases in quotation marks to provide lowercase aliases as you wanted.

perhaps your database's date language is non-english like mine(`turkish`), then you need to convert it to `english`.

lastly, it'a appropriate to order the results according to converted date, seen from your output. So we can use the following SQL :

```
   select to_char(to_date(date1,'yyyymmdd'),'dd-mm-yyyy') "date", 
          to_char(to_date(date1,'yyyymmdd'),'day','nls_date_language=english') "day"
     from days
    order by to_date(date1,'yyyymmdd');
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d20536/2)